# Is it safe to install Anaconda/Spyder/Python on laptop with netbanking?

Tags: banks

I am new to learning Python and I am using a laptop for netbanking etc.

Is it safe to use the same laptop for netbanking and installing packages like Anaconda/Spyder/Python on the same laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not "safe" in the meaning of "no risk at all" to install any kind of software on the same device you use for online banking since you don't know what the software is actually doing. This does not matter if this is open source or closed source software.

But, it is also not "safe" in the same "no risk" meaning to use online banking at all or to use a laptop, because you cannot fully trust the online banking, the browser you use, the operating system or the hardware and firmware of the laptop. Additionally you cannot fully trust your internet provider, the vendor of the router etc.

This means, that there is no such thing as "safe" in the meaning of "no risk". There is always some risk and the question is if this risk can be accepted. In the case of installing a widely used software from a well known source and keeping the software up-to-date the risk is probably acceptable. But, if you got the software on an USB stick from a suspicious person I would probably not trust it even if the person claims that this is the well known and widely used software you can also download. And, if the download was not done from the original site I would be suspicious too.

But, even if the download was done from the official site it still might be malicious in case the download site was infected. Thus, again, the risk is not zero. But, this is true not only for open source software but also for closed source.

In summary: the risk is never zero and the more software you install your on your system the larger the attack surface gets. You have to decide yourself if the risk is acceptable or not based on various factors. Closed source vs open source software might be such a factor but there are way more relevant ones, like download source or reputation of the vendor or author of the software.

Answer (score 1):

I taught a CSE course 'Introduction to Programming' and we used Python programming to teach the class. We always recommend that students install Anaconda Spyder for the purposes of the class -- both on their personal computers and on the university lab computers.

There is no such thing as 100% guarantees of security, but over the years we have never had 'trojan' or 'spyware' or any malware related issues with Anaconda and neither has anyone else (no known reported cases to the best of my knowledge).

So the answer to your question is: yes, it is safe. Go ahead and install it from the official source/website.